# QGIS 2.14 Couldn't load plugin 'processing' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, ascii

I understand that my problem originates from the letters in my username which apparently are non-ascii and very Nordic. I just have absolutely no clue how to get around this. I'm on Windows 10 64bit and QGIS is 2.14 Wien, not 2.14.1.

I don't really want to create a separate user account only for QGIS. Is there a way I can make QGIS "understand" my filepath without changing my username's lettering. What's weird is that I've not had any problems using QGIS with this error message popping up every time I start the program. Every analysis I've churned out has checked out accurately. The headache this error has given me has been purely cosmetic as far as I know.

So is there a pain-free workaround?

Here's my error message poem:

```
2016-05-02T16:19:19 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 306, in startPlugin
                plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
              File "C:/Users/V�iski/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 37, in classFactory
                from processing.ProcessingPlugin import ProcessingPlugin
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/Users/V�iski/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\ProcessingPlugin.py", line 47, in <module>
                if cmd_folder not in sys.path:
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 58, in showWarning
                "warning:%s\ntraceback:%s" % (warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno), stk),
            UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: C:/Users/V�iski/ is not a valid path for QGIS (� =non ASCII character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a partitioned drive you can make your life easy by working from the "D"-drive or whatever, as paths originating from there don´t contain your username.